# How to achieve dynamic products using front-end form

Tags: expresso-store, safecracker, expresso

We are doing a web app using ExpressionEngine where users create events (on the front end). Participants can register as an individual participant and participants can also register in groups of 2-5, either paying for themselves or for the group. Participants can add extras to their registration before checkout; these add-ons are determined by the original user who created the event.

Using Expresso Store, we'd like to ensure users can indeed create products (their registrations) from the front end, making them configurable by the participants before adding to the cart using options under Product Modifiers (eg. purchase lunch, or an event tshirt). Then have the participants add the group's registration or just some of the participants' registrations (including add ons) to the cart and check out.

We will also need a way for the participants to get notified when they've been added to a group, but have yet for their registration to be paid.

Is that all do-able using front end exp:channel:form tags? Any pointers, tips or show stoppers in this?

Thank you!!

Ps. If we should have gone with Cartthrob, let me know too! Not too late to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is completely doable with Store and I have done it myself in the past. The big issue with the modifiers is if you want to customize the look and feel of the fieldtype. If you want to do that, you will have to match the submission structure of data.

The Store fieldtype is setup to make it very easy to enter product details, but if you want to customize this in Channel Form, that is where you would need to do some custom tweaking.